# iOS Crashlytics app not showing crashes in portal for the AppStore app

Tags: ios, crashlytics

any ideas why my app is not showing crashes in crashlytics portal for the appstore app?
Have the run script setup just fine in the build phase, and worked fine during dev.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hemal from Crashlytics here. We'll treat each target and bundle ID like a separate app so make sure the app store build was onboarded the same way as the dev build! It should include the RunScript Build Phase, the Framework in the project directory and the startWithAPIKey in your code. Once you build and run your app you'll be good to go :)

Hemal